# Mplayer ios remote

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, video

I use mplayer to watch videos.

Is there a remote app that can control the mplayer from an ipad?

Just like Apple's Remote does for itunes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used nearly every IOS remote product known to man looking for the right XBMC remote for my IOS devices. Rowmote is a great app that gets the job done for mplayer and many more. As of last update it works for Front Row, Airfoil Video, Adobe Lightroom 2 or later, Amarra, Aperture, Boxee, DVD Player. eyeTV, Firefox, Hulu Desktop, iPhoto, iStopMotion, iTunes, Keynote ’08 and ‘09, kJams Pro, Last.fm, Logic Pro, Movist, mPlayer, OpenOffice Impress, PandoraBoy, PandoraJam, PandoraOne Desktop, Plex, Powerpoint 2004 and later, Preview, Quicktime, Safari, Skim, Songbird, Spotify, The Tube, VLC, and XBMC.

http://www.regularrateandrhythm.com/apps/rowmote-pro/